# Unable to capture token value from text file into a variable?

Tags: batch-file

Text file Content :

```
{"progress":"2","type":"info","message":"Automatic Installation initiated."},"5":{"progress":"20.25","type":"info","message":"Checking connectivity to Internet and management system."}},"install_progress":0,"logFileName":"FWF61E4Q16001577_2018-4-5_12_58_57.log"},"token":"gDDJ7uZx"}
{"progress":"30","type":"info","message":"Retrieving site specific information from management system."}
```

I am using this command to capture a token value:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('findstr "token" test.txt') do set "filecontent=%%x"
echo %filecontent%
for /f "delims=token" %%i in ("%filecontent%") do set tokenvalue=%%i
echo %tokenvalue%
```

Expected Output : `gDDJ7uZx`

I am unable to find a way using which I can capture token value as a output

Please assist me on this.

Answer (score 1):

with `for /f`, `delims` is a collection of single-char-delimiters (there is no string delimiter). So `delims=token` will delimit at every `t`, `o`, `k`, `e` and `n`.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type t.txt^|find "token"') do set "line=%%a"
for /f delims^=^" %%a in ("%line:*"token":=%") do set "line=%%a"
echo %line%
```

I worked with two lines; the first one to get the line, the second one to get the requested token.
Also I deleted the part from the start to (including) `token` with `set` substring substitution, before using the second `for /f` to extract the requested token (because it's possibly not sure, how the string exactly looks like)

**EDIT** your code from a comment (I had a hard time to format it correctly) is wrong in so much places, I won't number them up:

```
set %tokenfoundFirstTime=0 
findstr /c:"token" test.file 
if %errorlevel%==0 ( 
  if %tokenfoundFirstTime%==1 ( 
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.txt^|find "token"') do set "line=%%a" 
    for /f "delims^=^" %%a in ("%line:*"token":=%") do set "line=%%a" 
    echo %line% 
    SET tokenValue=%line%   
    set tokenfoundFirstTime=2 
  ) 
)
```

Compare it to the corrected version below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set tokenfoundFirstTime=0
findstr /c:"token" test.file >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  if %tokenfoundFirstTime%==0 ( 
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.file^|find "token"') do set "line=%%a"
    for /f delims^=^" %%a in ("!line:*"token":=!") do set "line=%%a"
    SET "tokenValue=!line!"
    set tokenfoundFirstTime=2
  ) 
)
echo %tokenvalue%
```

(I see no need and no value for `tokenfoundFirsttime` and the corresponding `if`, but left it there because maybe yu have more code not shown and may need it somehow.)

Comment: In the second `for /F` loop you forgot a `"` in the parentheses like `("%line:*"token":=%")`, or you forgot to escape the first or last one, in order to avoid a syntax error...

Comment: @aschipfl: works with or without it for me. Added anyways.

Comment: Just found out that the original code works in a batch file but throws a syntax error in command prompt... thanks anyway...

Comment: @aschipfl - ???? - the original code works fine for me from the command line as long as I change `%%a` to `%a`. The unbalanced quotes disappear after the percent expansion phase in both batch and command line mode. But the code certainly looks cleaner with balanced quotes.

Comment: yes, I added the `"` because of "certainly looks cleaner with balanced quotes"

Comment: @dbenham, you're absolutely right, I should have copied the code into `cmd` rather than retyping it; of course now it works, so I guess I have made some typo earlier...

Answer (score 0):

I am getting Syntax error while using this statement

for /f delims^=^" %%a in ("%line:*"token":=%") do set "line=%%a"

Please correct it

Comment: what's the exact error text? (PS: don't use answers for clarification or further questions; it will be downvoted and closed soon; use the Comment feature instead)

Comment: can't replicate. Using the code in my answer and the text in your question, I get exactly `gDDJ7uZx`. No errrors at all.

Comment: Actually i am using this code like this :

set %tokenfoundFirstTime=0


findstr /c:"token" test.file

if %errorlevel%==0 (

 if %tokenfoundFirstTime%==1 (

 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.txt^|find "token"') do set "line=%%a"

 for /f "delims^=^" %%a in ("%line:*"token":=%") do set "line=%%a"

 echo %line% 

 SET tokenValue=%line% 

 set tokenfoundFirstTime=2

 )

)
Getting Syntax error : The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Please assist me at which point i am doing wrong.